# How to read.table with "Hebrew" column names (in R)?

Tags: r, utf-8, hebrew

I am trying to read a .txt file, with Hebrew column names, but without success.

I uploaded an example file to:
http://www.talgalili.com/files/aa.txt

And am trying the command:

```
read.table("http://www.talgalili.com/files/aa.txt", header = T, sep = "\t")
```

This returns me with:

```
  X.....ª X...ª...... X...œ....
1      12          97         6
2     123         354        44
3       6           1         3
```

Instead of:

```
אחת שתיים   שלוש
12  97  6
123 354 44
6   1   3
```

My output for:

```
l10n_info()
```

Is:

```
$MBCS
[1] FALSE

$`UTF-8`
[1] FALSE

$`Latin-1`
[1] TRUE

$codepage
[1] 1252
```

And for:

```
Sys.getlocale()
```

Is:

```
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Can you suggest to me what to try and change to allow me to load the file correctly ?

**Update:**
Trying to use:

```
read.table("http://www.talgalili.com/files/aa.txt",fileEncoding ="iso8859-8")
```

Has resulted in:

```
 V1
1  ?
Warning messages:
1: In read.table("http://www.talgalili.com/files/aa.txt", fileEncoding = "iso8859-8") :
  invalid input found on input connection 'http://www.talgalili.com/files/aa.txt'
2: In read.table("http://www.talgalili.com/files/aa.txt", fileEncoding = "iso8859-8") :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'http://www.talgalili.com/files/aa.txt'
```

While also trying this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Or this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8")
```

Get's me this:

```
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored
```

Finally, here is the > sessionInfo()

```
R version 2.10.1 (2009-12-14) 
i386-pc-mingw32 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1255  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.10.1
```

Any suggestion or clarification will be appreciated.

Best,
Tal

Comment: did you ever figure out a way to set the locale? I am running into the same issue that you are and need to set it to use `odfWeave`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try passing parameter `fileEncoding` to read.table with a value of `iso8859-8`.

Use `iconvlist()` to get an alphabetical list of the supported encodings. As I saw [here](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/ISOcodes/html/ISO_8859.html) Hebrew must be part 8 of ISO 8859.

Comment: The file also reads fine for me in UTF-8, so that might be an option as well. File encodings in R have always been trial and error for me.

My Sys.getlocale():
[1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: Same here, it works. I have Sys.getlocale() en_US.UTF-8 --- $MBCS [1] TRUE --- $`UTF-8` [1] TRUE --- $`Latin-1` [1] FALSE

Comment: Dear gd047, Kevin and Thrawn.  I tried gd047 solution and to change to your configuration, and failed in doing so. I updated the main question to reflect that. Any suggestions will be most welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: Two more thoughts: (1) What does sessionInfo() report? What platform? (2) Can you read without the header line and then add the labels afterwards? E.g., read.table(...)[-1, ]; then add column names with names(). I'm wondering if the problem is not with reading the table but handling Hebrew characters in R. Is there a Hebrew locale?

Comment: Hi Kevin. I added the sessioninfo in the question. The problem is because of the Hebrew - but that is the problem I wish to resolve :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried @George Donats answer, but couldn't make it work. So I wanted to suggest another possibility for future reference.

I couldn't find the file online, so I've recreated a txt file like your using TAB as a seperator. You can load it into R with the Hebrew text using a connection. It is demonstrated below:

```
con<-file("aa.txt",open="r",encoding="iso8859-8") ##Open a read-only connection with encoding fit for Hebrew (iso8859-8)
```

Than you can load it into R with your code, using con variable as the file input, code described here:

```
data<-read.table(con,sep="\t",header=TRUE)
```

Browsing into the data variable gives the following results:

```
str(data)

'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ אחת  : int  6 44 3
 $ שתיים: int  97 354 1
 $ שלוש : int  12 123 6

> data$אחת
[1]  6 44  3
```

Comment: How exactly did @George-Dontas approach not work? Please post error message and platform information.

Comment: @smci it was a wgile ago and I can't really remember the error msg. However I managed to make it work with the process described above. I will make sure to provide error msg. next time.

Comment: No probs. This platform support in R is as flaky as anything, and the error messages are very bad-quality. It would be good to raise some bugs and make the damn thing more robust.