# How can I read a .doc file in R, in Hebrew?

Tags: r

I have tried about 6 different packages for reading .doc files, and non of them handled Hebrew encoding very well. If anyone has a solution, I will be most grateful!
I have tried 'readr', 'textreadr', 'readtext', 'tm', and 'antiword'. The problem is always the same, outputting question marks where hebrew letters should be, For example:

```
> readr::read_document("F:/worm/H201502750_388971_3.doc") 
[1] "????? ????? ???? ????? ??' 02-5429496" 
[2] "??? ??????? ????????? ???' 02-5429674" 
[3] "?????? ?????? ????? ?. ?????
```

Comment: You'll improve your chances of getting a useful answer if you mention the packages you've already tried, and the problems they created.

Comment: I have tried 'readr', 'textreadr', 'readtext', 'tm', and 'antiword'. The problem is always the same, outputting question marks where hebrew letters should be, For example: `> read_document("F:/worm/H201502750_388971_3.doc")`
 [1] "????? ?????    ???? ?????    ??' 02-5429496"                                    
 [2] "??? ??????? ?????????  ???' 02-5429674"                                         
 [3] "?????? ?????? ?????    ?. ????? 11.02.2015"

Comment: based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471075/how-to-read-table-with-hebrew-column-names-in-r) I wonder whether `readr::read_document("F:/worm/H201502750_388971_3.doc", locale=locale(encoding = "iso8859-8"))`  would work. If not, you might need to provide a link to an example file to test code on.